# Where I can find visitor analytics for my website on the craft backend?

Tags: analytics

I would like to see visitor analytics for the website, specific pages, etc. but I don't see that information. Seems like it should be simple to find. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

By default, Craft doesn't come with any analytics or statistics tool. Craft doesn't make any assumption about your site, including whether your site has 'visitors' in the traditional sense and whether you want to track any statistics or other metrics.

There are a lot of plugins that either provide an integrated statistics tool or integrate third-party tools. Check out the [plugin store](https://plugins.craftcms.com/search?q=analytics&tab=plugins&craft4) to find something that you like.